# How to design websites for all display sizes

Tags: html, css, user-interface, slice

I like to use a lot of unique graphics on my pages, which often results in making different page sizes depending on available screen width/height.

Here are two examples:

http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/ - the image floats at the bottom of my screen but on a larger browser, the image floats near the middle making it look off. It looks best when the bottom of the window aligns with the bottom of the image

www.stevenlebel.com - it loads two different pages depending on what monitor size is detected.

This seems like a lot of redundant coding. My question is, how can I make sliced/Photoshop images transition well to different screen sizes. Does Photoshop allow you to make DIVS instead of tables?
Can i make each of the slices created by Photoshop grow/shrink when the browser window size changes?

If anyone has any input on creating websites like this I would be very interested to hear what they have to say.

Thanks

Katie

Comment: since this is an open ended question I figured I would post some things I thought were relevant to see what people have to say

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/web-design-html-and-css/threads/217982/setting-photoshop-to-produce-div-and-css

Comment: A first step would be not letting PS write your HTML for you.

Comment: i have no problem writing html. I just didnt know a better way necessarily. I also now see that it can export divs and css so why not let it write the html for me?

Comment: I was hoping this could be more of a discussion of design rather than a question of my skills

Comment: @JamWaffles How do you think I should code a website such as the ones above. Would you use a big sprite sheet and move the location depending on the image needed. how do I position all of the images without using a table or div height/width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of [media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/) with properly selected [breakpoints](http://www.vanseodesign.com/web-design/media-query-breakpoints/), sprites or individual images, and even a library like [foresight.js](https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js?utm_source=html5weekly) you can achieve the results you're looking for.

The media queries will allow you to set up your site for different screen groups with breakpoints set to cover most tablets, phones, etc. You could then load a different image version from a sprite or a separate image entirely. Finally, foresight.js will look at screen resolution and available bandwidth to load higher resolution images for retina browsers if so desired.

Answer (score 0):

set the page size as

```
.page
        { 
        width:100%
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a tour on [mediaqueri.es](http://mediaqueri.es/) and find out how others have solved your problem and don't forget [dribbble](http://dribbble.com/) also. I think you know about web designing for PCs, others are smart phones, tablets and TVs. Get some basic understanding of the user interfaces of apps on mobile OSes. Read the [Android Design](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html), [App Design Strategies for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppDesign/AppDesign.html) and [Designing UX for apps for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779072.aspx). After that I think you'll have a proper design to solve your question. Then learn about [css3 media queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/), start coding with [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) and start from the mobile design. Good luck!